# strapi v4 missing Create is owner policy

Tags: strapi

please help me.
I could not return the data created by each logged in user.
Where can I be wrong?

```html
const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController(
  "api::pessoalfinanca.pessoalfinanca",
  ({ strapi }) => ({
    async create(ctx) {
      let entity;
      ctx.request.body.data.colaborador = ctx.state.user;
      entity = await super.create(ctx);
      return entity;
    },
    async find(ctx) {
      const { data, meta } = await super.find(ctx);
      return { data, meta };
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: Does your create method work? Does it add the colaborador field? If so then check that the request (ctx in your find method) has the `colaborador` flag too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should pass id, not user object

```
ctx.request.body.data.colaborador = ctx.state.user.id;
```

It would also be advisable to check if a user is logged in, to avoid possible exceptions when using user.id

Complete code:

```
 async create(ctx) {
      const { user } = ctx.state;
      if (!user) return ctx.unauthorized();
      let entity;
      ctx.request.body.data.colaborador = user.id;
      entity = await super.create(ctx);
      return entity;
    },
```